# Футер в положении bottom

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы футер при изменении размеров экрана всегда оставался внизу экрана браузера, кроссбраузерно конечно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS свойство position: fixed, так-же стоит не забывать про z-index, что-бы не было проблем с тем, что-бы тело страницы заходило "под него"

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="footer" style="position: absolute; height: 80px; width: 100%; border-top: 1px solid; bottom: 0px;">Footer</div>
```